# JavaScript removing the zeros from front of a number

Tags: javascript

I have been writing a program to count the number of zeros in a number.

I implemented the following:

```js
let num = 00012340000, count = 0, digits;
digits = num.toString().split("");
console.log(digits)
for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(digits[i]) == 0) {
    count++
  }
}
console.log(count)
```

The entire digit's value changes and the program automatically strip off the zeros from the front.

```js
[
  '2', '7', '3',
  '6', '1', '2',
  '8'
]
```

Can anyone please suggest what is responsible for this behavior?

Comment: Integers don't start with 0s. Make it a string.

Comment: A numeric literal starting with 0 is _octal_, and toString won't include leading zeros. If you want exactly those digits, _use a string_.

Comment: only strings can start with 0s and not integers and numbers

Comment: Here are some tips: Numbers starting with a 0 are treated as octal. `00012340000 === 2736128`, `12340000 !== 12340000`  and `01234 !== "01234"` You should use strings if you want to treat numbers literally as written.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the leading zeros, you can use a while loop and check the character at the current position.

```js
/**
 * Counts the number of leading zeros in a numeric string.
 * @param {string} num - number with zero-or-more leading zeros
 * @returns {number} the amount of leading zeros
 */
const countLeadingZeros = (num) => {
  let count = 0;
  while (count < num.length && num.charAt(count) === '0') { count++; }
  return count;
}

console.log(countLeadingZeros('00012340000')); // Pass-in a string value
```